# What is the easiest and informal way to remember XOR and Inclusive-OR logic?

Tags: xor

If I find hard to remember XOR and Inclusive-OR, what is the easiest way to remember the logic and truth table?

Comment: I feel this is not a programming question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**XOR**: One or the other, but not both

**OR**: One, or the other, or both

One way to think about it is that XOR (eXclusive-OR) is exclusively OR and *not* AND. Another way is that XOR is exclusive in that you can only pick one of the options: i.e. "You can't have your cake and eat it too."

Answer (score 1):

Inclusive OR :
"false if both values are false"

XOR :"false if both values are same"